# RVM forgets settings across reboot (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, bundler, gemset

Stuck.

I thought I installed RVM on this fresh ubuntu 20.04 box using the same commands I used on my old 19.10 box:

(from https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm)

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rvm
rvm install ruby
sudo apt install ruby-bundler
echo 'source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
rvm use 2.7.0
rvm gemset create FOO
rvm gemset use FOO
gem install jekyll
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

However, my gemsets and ruby installs seem to disappear each time I reboot now. (This was not a problem before.)

My current workaround: 
When `bundle exec jekyll serve` fails, I run these commands to get it working again:

```
rvm use --default 2.7.0
rvm gemset create FOO
rvm gemset use FOO
gem install jekyll
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

I thought I have read the relevant docs at rvm.io, but clearly I am missing something...

Comment: _I thought I installed RVM using the same commands_ What commands? It's more important to know how you got to this point than it is to know what you do to patch it.

Comment: @anothermh Certainly. Updated question.

Comment: @user2901351 - Did you get a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue with rvm

Comment: not to turn this into a back-n-forth, but : Yes. I figured out some solution, and should have followed up here. Let me look into...